# HTML SELECT is not listing in a single click in IE

Tags: html, extjs

I have a HTML SELECT in my ExtJS application. This is working fine in chrome. But in IE the dropdown is not expanding in single click. Below is the code

```
<div id='Simple'><select name='selectStmt' style='width:75%;'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: what IE version? is the code you provided enough to reproduce the issue?

Comment: IM using IE 8.. yes This simple code is working in Chrome. But in IE im facing problem.

Comment: I ran your code in IE 10 using browser mode = IE 8. the select opens with a single click. have you tried only this code in blank page, no css?

Comment: It works in IE8 for me: http://jsbin.com/edAxUQO/1/edit